# How to use browserify with react across source trees?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify

I have a web app that breaks code into modules in a lib/ directory.  Each module has a static/ directory that gets served from a different domain as well as a jsx/ directory for React files that get compiled into the static/ directory.  A sample source tree might look like this:

```
.../
   -> lib/
         -> product1/
                    ... project 1 files ...
                    -> jsx/
                    -> static/
         -> product2/
                    ... project 2 files ...
                    -> jsx/
                    -> static/
```

I have a script that monitors these directories, recompiles jsx into static directory, then creates a package with browserify for each major module (above, e.g.: product1.bundle.js, product2.bundle.js)

However, with this structure, requiring a module across products doesn't work. (IE, I want to make my own reusable ui components in a separate module) Browserify can't find it in the source tree because of the nested structure, and if I use --ignore-missing, it is not exposed by browserify in the bundle.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling from JSX to JS as a separate process, just use a browserify transform: reactify.

```
npm install --save-dev reactify
```

In your package.json:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["reactify"]
}
```

You have a few options for accessing your reusable components.  The easiest, but most annoying and typo-prone is to just do `require('../.././../foo.jsx')`.

An alternative is to make it its own package.  You can then symlink it into node_modules

```
ln -s ./src/js/common node_modules/
```

Or put it in a separate git repo, and npm install from there.  Or create snapshot tar archives, and npm install those (either over network or with a relative path).

Comment: I don't suppose there is a $PATH equivalent for searching for modules, then?  The long paths are annoying. :)